# How can I customize the frame size of the Android camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am wondering whether it is possible to set the size of the Android camera's frame through the native camera app. The goal is to be able to take pictures of a certain format (where height == width). I have looked at the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) but it seems that the only parameter that can be passed to the intent (`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) is `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to define the path in which the picture will be saved.

Any idea? (If it's not possible I guess I'll need to let the user crop the picture to make it fit in a given square).

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like this topic has already been addressed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328721/change-camera-settings-from-another-apps-activity ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize it, as long as this is format offered by camera service. (See camera API)
But even this does not mean that desired resolution is actually supported.   When you are using intent, you are invokinng installed camera appliaction - it may provide some ways of customisation via intent, but it is not defined in standart and not portable between different vendors.

Your best option is to post process image and crop it after it is taken

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question to clarify that I wanted to do that through the native camera app service.

Comment: In this case you are at mercy of android image vendor - no standarts or portability there